# PowerBI show wrong data by connecting with Google Analytics if I apply a Data Filter Inside the query

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi

I'm getting the same kind of issue with "Events".

I'm trying to track the creation of Invoice Disputes (when the clint detect some error in the invoice) for March '19.

The thing is that when I get the data for the event without filter nothing in the query (in order to use the filters on the Report tab) I get the value of 316. BUT i know that the correct Value is 302.

[Wrong Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb2C6.png)

So I tried to filter the month directly on the query before load the data and guess what? the correct value shows up.

[Correct Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s54eQ.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure you are using distinct count for card visual if your event count twice being same id or name.

Comment: Mmm I think that do not apply, because the unique evens of Google Analytics already bring you a unique value, you only have to sum them.